# Transferencia de Archivos entre Servidores

Tags: android

Mi aplicacion al Escanear el codigo de barras detecta la locacion de un archivo en el servidor

**Como puedo lograr mandarle al servidor 2 la direccion del archivo y que el haga la transferencia del archivo?**

Comment: la opcion mas facil es compartir los directorios donde esta el servidor, de esta manera tendras una hubicacion en la red a la cual copiar y pegar. ejemplo : >compartir servidorA :\documentosApp\documentosCompartidos con UsuarioApp ahora UsuarioApp podra navegar e interactuar con \\\servidorA\DocumentosCompartidos\

Comment: Si Mike tengo las carpetas compartidas en los 2 servidores, pero no encuentro la manera en copiar la informacion de la carpeta compartida en el servidor 1 en la carpeta compartida de el servidor 2

Comment: aqui hay una respuesta con un codigo de como copiar en andriod, solo reemplaza tus rutas por las rutas compartidas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292954/how-to-make-a-copy-of-a-file-in-android

Comment: Mike a la hora de querer mover los archivos me tira este error:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/10.1.191.40/Compartido/3.pdf: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) 

Estoy creando mal los archivos?

File gdist = new File("file://10.1.191.40/Compartido/3.pdf");

Comment: necesitas usar doble contradiagonal al inicio, si es web tienes que usar la siguiente nomenclatura "file:\\\10.1.191.40/Compartido/3.pdf"

Comment: He luchado y sigue sin dejarme mover los archivos siempre me da el mismo error :(